# SVN - Checksum mismatch while updating

Tags: svn

When I try to update some files from Subversion, I get the error:

```
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: 
Checksum mismatch while updating 'D:\WWW\Project\\.svn\text-base\import.php.svn-base'; expected: '3f9fd4dd7d1a0304d8020f73300a3e07', actual: 'cd669dce5300d7035eccb543461a961e'
```

Why do I get this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The easiest way to fix it (if you don't have many changes) is to copy your changes to another directory, delete the directory where your project is checked out, and checkout the project again.

Then copy your changes back in (don't copy any .svn folders) and commit, and continue.

Comment: I just deleted the folder where was a problem file and I updated the entire project. Now it seems to be ok.

Comment: +1 The other alternative I found left me hacking the svn database, much easier

Comment: @SeanDowney how to do that ?

Comment: @arvindwill Sorry, I wasn't very clear in my comment, this method is much easier. Here is the scary alternative: http://maymay.net/blog/2008/06/17/fix-subversion-checksum-mismatch-error-by-editing-svnentries-file/

Comment: This is only the easiest way to do it if your repo is fairly small.

Comment: This is not a specific fix at all. You can always delete all your local data and start with a fresh copy from the repo.

Comment: This did not work for me. After adding my changes back in, the checksums failed to match again

Answer (score 219):

In case you are using SVN 1.7+ there is a workaround described [here](http://techblog.moudrick.net/2012/02/subversion-17-file-folders-manipulation.html).

Just to recap:

1. Go to the folder with the file causing problems
2. Execute command `svn update --set-depth empty` (note: this will delete your files, so make a copy first!)
3. Execute command `svn update --set-depth infinity`

Comment: While this worked for me, note "svn update --set-depth empty" will delete everything from that path, so make a copy first

Comment: This worked great for fixing a giant repository at a remote location. While doing a new checkout would have worked, it would have taken over an hour; this took minutes.

Comment: hi i have using window and tortoisesvn as svn client .. I was try your solution .but it still show the  isse

Comment: Just replaced .svn directory from new repository to the old, it worked :)

Comment: This worked great for me, thanks! It's worth noting that point #1 is to drill down to the actual folder (or file) that is causing the problem. Then you don't have to update much. I had a folder with a few dozen files in it which I used Tortoise "Update To->only this item" on the folder and then "Update To->fully recursive" to get it all back. Still everyone beware that this deletes the files in that folder! On a slow VPN link with a many-gigabyte repo and finely tuned --set-depths throughout, the "standard" solution was simply useless.

Comment: Worked for me, and it didn't everything from the path.

Comment: Though it worked for some files, it did not work for others for me

Comment: Note that you can "svn update --set-depth exclude file.foo" and "svn update file.foo" to operate on one file only, not a whole folder.

Answer (score 7):

I had a simllar problem. Main provider was antivirus "FortiClient" (antivirus + VPN CLient). When I disabled it - all update/checkout was made correctly

Comment: This is the only answer that solved my problem. I could never thought of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I found an easier way to fix this issue.
You cannot do this directly from eclipse. 
Steps:

1. Navigate to the workspace folder structure in windows
2. rename the folder
3. refresh in eclipse
4. Now the folder and files will be removed from project in eclipse and will appear under new renamed folder
5. Now try "Synchronise with Respository" option.

This will restore text base folder in .svnfolder . Checksum mismatch while updating error will not appear further.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me using the Eclipse plug-in and synchronizing. The file causing the issue had no local changes (and in fact no remote changes since my last update). I chose "revert" for the file, with no other modifications to the files, and things returned to normal.

Answer (score 1):

I had a the same error but for one file.  In IntelliJ IDEA I was able to make a copy of the file, then go into the project and delete the file in question, then commit successfully.  Then, I made a new file with the same name and copy the contents back into it.  I guess you would lose the revision history but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error and fixed as follows:

(My 'fix' is based on an assumption which may or may not be correct as I don't know that much about how subversion works internally, but it definitely worked for me)

I am assuming that .svn\text-base\import.php.svn-base is expected to match the latest commit.

When I checked the file I was having the error on , the base file did NOT match the latest commit in the repository.

I copied the text from the latest commit and saved that in the .svn folder, replacing the incorrect file (made a backup copy in case my assumptions were wrong). (file was marked read only, I cleared that flag, overwrote and set it back to read only)

I was then able to commit successfully.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a colleague working with you:

1) ask him to rename the file causing problems and `commit`

2) you `update` (now you see the file with invalid checksum with different name)

3) rename it back to its original name

4) `commit` (and ask you colleague to `update` to get back the file name in its initial state)

This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found very nice solution, that **SOLVED** my problem. The trick is to edit the svn DB (wc.db).

The solution is described on this page : http://www.exchangeconcept.com/2015/01/svn-e155037-previous-operation-has-not-finished-run-cleanup-if-it-was-interrupted/

If link is down, just look and follow this instructions:
[image]

I used sqlite tool from http://sqlitebrowser.org/.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Tortoise SVN, after tring all solution in this page and not working,

I finally back up the problem file. and use `Repo Browser` delete the problem file in it, then update local folder so the file in local folder is deleted. Then copy back the backup file and `Add > Commit`, then I can update successfully.

The only disadvantage of this method is the history of this file will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this follow following steps:

1. Open the entries file located in .svn directory where you are getting the error.
2. Find the entry for the file giving error and replace the expected value with actual value in error.
3. Now synchronize and try to update.

If it still does not work. Try these. Its just a workaround though:

1. Delete the file from your system.
2. Delete the entry of the file from entries file. (Starting from the name of the file till the special characters).
3. Now Synchronize and update the file.

This will get latest version of file from repository and all conflicts will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

had a similiar issue on a server but the SVN directory was very large , didn't want to delete and resync so I just made a copy of the files locally and then deleted them.  When update succeeded and added files back in.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the file and remove the file reference from file entries under the .svn directory

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:

1. Execute svn cleanup from file system
2. Switch to another branch
3. Solve conflicts
4. Switch to the "problematic" branch
5. Execute cleanup from Spring Tool Suite
6. Execute Project Update

Answer (score 0):

1.'update to reversion' check 'only this item' under the directory
2.update again check 'Fully recursive'

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, what worked for me is.

1. Tried SVN checkout of the affected branch into a new directory
2. Waited till the .svn folder get added in the new directory
   3.Copied and replaced the old .svn directory from the affected branch with the new .svn directory
3. SVN Clean up
4. SVN Update

After following these steps I was not able to get the SVN checksum mismatch error and the Update was working as normal

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with `svnkit-1.10.71`. I compared the file I was getting from the server to the file I was uploading back to the server using `NotePad++`. There was an unexpected difference in the file. Even though I made sure to convert the bytes to UTF8 string, a character still ended up being encoded incorrectly. It was `ö` om `RÖMPP`. It got converted to something like `RÃ–MPP`. I change `ö` to `o`, and it fixed the problem. The file I am using should not have these special chars.