# Checksum mismatch on update: SVN v1.8.10

Tags: svn, checksum

I am getting this error while running `svn up` command: `svn: E200014: Checksum mismatch`.

I tried the solution here: [SVN - Checksum mismatch while updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352934/svn-checksum-mismatch-while-updating)
 (which involves running command `svn update --set-depth empty` and `svn update --set-depth infinity` in the directory with problematic file) but this doesn't work and I am still getting the same error.

Is there any other solution apart from checking out the whole repository again and copying back the changes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout a new working copy -- that one seems to be broken.

Note that SVN 1.8.10 is outdated. The latest version is 1.9.6, the latest maintenance update in 1.8.x release is 1.8.16.