# Is there a solution to fix SVN checksum mismatch permanently?

Tags: svn, checksum

I have almost searched all the solutions on the internet of the SVN checksum mismatch problem. The most useful solution for now is as follows:
[svn-checksum-mismatch-while-updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352934/svn-checksum-mismatch-while-updating)

But all the solutions now are just curing the symptoms, not the disease, After someone else commit the problem files again, I got the checksum mismatch problem again or if I modify the problem file and commit it, it will also cause the checksum mismatch problem. So this means, after I solved the checksum mismatch problem with the solution on the above link, as long as the problem files modified, the mismatch problem will show up again. The Error is:

```
svn: E155017: Working copy text base is corrupt
svn: E200014: Checksum mismatch for text base of'/home/phymin/projects/vehicularsystem20/src/VSL/control/ControlNode.cpp':
expected:  d5affa22f91f5c8f8001a1ef17cc8efc
actual:  f444d256fee6457d40ee38a3182da306
```

So, I'm here for the reason why this problem always happens, and how to fix this problem permanently? Any help will be appreciated.

BTW: I use TortiseSVN client, its version is 1.9.7

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the cause of this problem. That is we used an encrpytion software to encrpyt our code, and this problem is caused by a wrong configuration of the encrpytion software. Thanks for all your attention.