# Tortoise SVN Check-sum error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am having this weired SVN issue . I have a file when I try to commit it shows me following error.

```
Some resources were not updated.
svn: Checksum mismatch for 'C:\Users\xxx\workspace\Accounts1\.svn\text-base\manage_report.jsp.svn-base'; expected: 'd32ed2ae778b684ee496adc1386c2a6d', recorded: '25bb91909b02c117c206b5ad1ac5aa5b'
```

I tried to delete that file from SVN and adding a new file and still I am getting same error . I tried cleanup too.

What's reason causing this ? Thanks for any solutions .

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156431/tortoise-check-in-error-checksum-mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really hate copy-and-pasted urls pointing to solutions, as answers to questions, but this blog has a very long write-up:

http://andrew.hedges.name/blog/2009/01/25/how-to-recover-from-checksum-mismatch-errors-in-svn

Basically, from his blog, he says:

```
1.Check out the latest revision of the corrupted directory into a temporary directory
2.Delete the munged SVN revision files
3.Copy the correct SVN revision files into the working directory
```

Now, his directions are for mac, but...

- Replace `Terminal.app` with `cmd.exe`
- Replace `ls -la` with `dir`
- Replace `rm *` with `del *.*`
- Replace `cp *` with `copy *.*`

**Personally, I would make a copy of the ENTIRE checkout directory before proceeding. Also, read his warning/disclaimer.**

---

***EDIT: Update***

Additionally, one of the comments on that blog post has a lot of merit:

> This is a silly way.
>
> Why not just check in the files you can, move your working copy dir
>   somewhere, do an update to get a new working copy, and finally copy
>   the remaining files into the new working copy. Delete old working
>   copy. Done. No need to worry about .svn directories.
>
> Why be married to a busted working copy? Just ditch it.

Comment: Thanks I ended up deleting the file from repo and adding back again from scratch .